# Map physical path of a file to serve path for download

Tags: python, angularjs, django

In my AngularJS/Python app, I uploaded a file using `dropzone` which has a physical path of something like this:

`D:\uploadedFiles\tmpmj02zkex___5526310795850751687_n.jpg'`

Now I want to create a link for this file for display and download on the front end. A link that looks something like this:

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/uploadedFiles/tmpmj02zkex___5526310795850751687_n.jpg`

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add a url pattern in eg. `urls.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    ...,
    url(r'^uploadedFiles/(?P<file_name>.+)/$', views.download, name='download')
]
```

and a `download` method in the controller in eg. `views.py` as suggested in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36394206/1862500):

```
import os
from django.conf import settings
from django.http import HttpResponse

# path to the upload dir
UPLOAD_DIR = 'D:\uploadedFiles'

...

def download(request, file_name):
    file_path = os.path.join(UPLOAD_DIR, file_name)
    if os.path.exists(file_path):
        with open(file_path, 'rb') as fh:
            response = HttpResponse(fh.read(), content_type="application/octet-stream")
            response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=' + os.path.basename(file_path)
            return response
    else:
        raise Http404
```

Comment: do we need to specify the content type? the uploaded file can be of any type

Comment: No, we don't, but it is recommended as explained in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20392345/is-content-type-http-header-always-required). I've updated the example so that it always force user to download regardless the file type

Comment: I had to change url pattern to `url(r'^uploadedFiles/(?P<file_name>[\w\-.*]+)/$', download, name='download'),` and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: Great. Ah my bad, you are right. It can be even simpler `(?P<file_name>.+)` as suggested in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6164540/getting-two-strings-in-variable-from-url-in-django)